# Cloudflare A record status always On

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I need to make all of my fresh added A records status "ON" by default. So i want traffic to be routed through the CloudFlare in any case.
Is there any way to do this without switching it manually?

Comment: you can use API to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to automate this; but it isn't too hard in the admin panel, you just click on the grey cloud so it turns to an orange cloud.